# Split of Access Database in front end and back end DB

Tags: excel

Question. I currently have a front end Excel budgeting tool with an Access DB behind it. From this Excel tool users (approx. 10) will upload via ADO flat tables in the Database. Is it better to use a split database one with the tables only and the other one with the queries in it (queries the users will use to retrieve data again to the excel tool)? For example to avoid problems with multiple users uploading at the same time. I am not sure when for performance it is better to use two databases!

Thanks, 
Michiel

Answer (score 0):

Think i know the answer. Splitting the database is basically only useful when access is actually opened by users. In my case data is retrieved and uploaded via ado and therefore the database functionality is less hampered.